# Zoomcharts with preloaded data

Tags: zoomcharts

I am trying to use TimeChart with preloaded data, but I can't find a good example.

```
data = {'preloaded':{
    'unit':'s',
    'values':{'id':3,'name':'slice1','value':20}
}}
```

However I'm getting error: "Required field 'unit' not set in data"

Can you please recommend how specify the data properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
    var dataObj = {
        "dataLimitFrom":1279408157,
        "dataLimitTo":1384253671,
        "unit":"s",
        "values":[
          [1280062860,"8.221"],
          [1282209412,"4.2",],
          [1284577510,"5.9"],
          [1286988866,"1.52"],
        ]
    };
    var t = new TimeChart({
        container: document.getElementById("demo"),
        data:
        {
            units:["s"],
            timestampInSeconds: true,
            preloaded: dataObj
        }
    });
```

For TimeChart in data array first one is always timestamp [1280062860,"8.221"]. 
You can also change "unit" to any of ["s","m","h","d","M","y"]

More about timechart:
https://zoomcharts.com/developers/en/time-chart/api-reference/settings.html

**UPDATE:**
'data' array containing timestamps and values is now called 'values'.

Answer (score -1):

The first value in [data] is the difference between 1/1/1970 and the selected date in seconds/hour/minute/...